# R indexing in a function when using mapply

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, mapply

I'm a little new to the programming game.
I have before used foor-loops a lot but the datasets I'm working with is growing in size.

Therefore I'm migrating to apply, but it is something fundamental I'm lacking in understanding.
tried different things but cant get it to work.

Before I always had a variable that indices the row index as such.

```
z = 1 
for (i in x) {
execution[z, 3]
z = z + 1
}
```

in one or another form

Now that I'm transforming into mapply I'm confused about how to index the row the execution takes from.

At the moment I'm trying to flatten out information.
it comes in the form

postcode, street, startpoint housenumber, endpoint housenumber

as

123, main street, 1, 5

so I'm transforming into.

123, main street, 1

123, main street, 3

123, main street, 5

I have written a code that work for the index as such

```
i = 5
prov <- function(x = a) {

  len = seq(a[i,3], a[i,5], 2)
  a1 = rep(x = a[i, 1], times = length(len))
  a2 = rep(x = a[i, 2], times = length(len))
  a4 = rep(x = a[i, 4], times = length(len))
  a6 = rep(x = a[i, 6], times = length(len))
  a7 = rep(x = a[i, 7], times = length(len))
  a8 = rep(x = a[i, 8], times = length(len))
  a9 = rep(x = a[i, 9], times = length(len))
  a10 = rep(x = a[i, 10], times = length(len))
  a11= rep(x = a[i, 11], times = length(len))
  a12 = rep(x = a[i, 12], times = length(len))
  a13= rep(x = a[i, 13], times = length(len))
  a14 = rep(x = a[i, 14], times = length(len))
  a15 = rep(x = a[i, 15], times = length(len))
  a16 = rep(x = a[i, 16], times = length(len))
  a17 = rep(x = a[i, 17], times = length(len))
  a18 = rep(x = a[i, 18], times = length(len))
  
  tmatrix = cbind(a1, a2, len, a4, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18)
  return(tmatrix)
  
}
```

The function works with indexed i.
But I cant use in mapply. Either how do I find the index the execution is done on, or is there something else.

With best regards Kristian

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example that shows input, and expected output? I am a little confused as `a` is not defined. Thx

Comment: Hello!

Thank you for the time, the user below helped me.

But have a nice week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         housenumber = startpoint.housenumber) %>%
  group_by(row ) %>%
  complete(housenumber = seq(startpoint.housenumber, endpoint.housenumber, 2)) %>%
  fill(postcode, street) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(postcode, street, housenumber)

#   postcode street      housenumber
#     <int> <chr>             <dbl>
#1      123 main street           1
#2      123 main street           3
#3      123 main street           5
```

**data**

```
df <-structure(list(postcode = 123L, street = "main street", startpoint.housenumber = 1L, 
    endpoint.housenumber = 5L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Thank you!

Time for calculation went down from 6 days to 2 hours :)
Worked perfectly!

Comment: See there, a checkbox.

One really learns something new every day!